# PHP Curl request returns unsuccessful, how to circumvent robots.txt?

Tags: php, curl

I have a scraper that used to work, but now it is returning a 'request unsuccessful' page, presumably because of changed robots.txt settings. To address ethical issues now - I plan to switch to a different site, as this one updated their TOS and no longer likes crawlers. It is only a simple scraper and I can build a new one in an hour. However, I am interested in this from a technical standpoint, as I thought Curl was supposed to be able to mimic a browser request, and the site opens fine through a browser.

However, this is what I get instead of the page content when using Curl:

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=9&xinfo=7-43571122-0 0NNY RT(1459673434797 0) q(0 -1 -1 -1) r(0 -1) B12(4,315,0) U2&incident_id=133001530113712368-463745872568846743&edet=12&cinfo=04000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 133001530113712368-463745872568846743</iframe></body></html>
```

The same is received when I try a simple `file_get_contents` instead of Curl.

This is my Curl code:

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => [
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
            ]
        ));
        $raw = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

There is suprisingly little on this issue online. Based on some similar ones I found, I have also tried adding `CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5'`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0`, `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3` but to no avail.

I have also tried both `http` and `https` in the target URL - in the browser is seems to load `https` automatically, though I am not sure if this was always the case.

Does anyone know why Curl is failing and what might be the solution?

Comment: I highly doubt [Incapsula](https://www.incapsula.com/website-security/access-control.html) is going to tell you how they figured out your program was identified as a scraper - people pay them to keep bots and scrapers out.... Some general info about scraper detection can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372115/the-way-to-detect-web-scraping).